# Android image picker from gallery error

Tags: android, image, gallery, android-gallery

Im having this problem when I select an image from my gallery.
For some reason it doesn't work on my phone (Galaxy s3, 4.4.2) but works fine on other devices (one of them is Galaxy s3 4.2.2).
In my manifiest file the target is 19.
Here is the log:

> 04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186): Process: com.appgate.homeland, PID: 11186
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2002, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:38468 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.appgate.homeland/main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3385)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3428)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1254)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5142)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at java.io.File.(File.java:134)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at com.appgate.homeland.model.ImagePicker.getPathAndCopy(ImagePicker.java:147)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at com.appgate.homeland.model.ImagePicker.onActivityResult(ImagePicker.java:81)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at com.zlotindaniel.library.controller.activity.SuperActivity.onActivityResult(SuperActivity.java:262)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5433)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3381)
>   04-09 16:46:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11186):    ... 11 more

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code below to open Gallery dialog.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    // intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Photo"),
            GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```